# How to use lottieanimation in android 12 splash screen?

Tags: android, splash-screen, lottie, android-12

I'm migrating to Android 12 and the API has introduced a system splash screen. I want to show a Lottie animation in the splash screen how can I achieve this with the splash screen API recommended by google?

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to do this, however, there is a trick that was described by one of the developers of the SplashScreen API.
You can find the details here: https://github.com/vcaen/splashscreen-sample/tree/main/lottiesample